# I am trying to figure out how to change the format of the date displayed on my page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form with a date field that passes the event date to the DB. Later that data is fetched and displayed on another page, but it is being displayed as yyyy/mm/dd and I would like it to be in mm/dd/yyyy format. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you looked at php.net ? (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Please share with us the code you currently use to display the date, as well as the format of the date as stored in the database.

Comment: You just want to reformat the string, so `'2019/01/29'.replace(/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/, '$2/$3/$1')` will do the job in javascript. But mm/dd/yyyy is ambiguous, so please don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the built in `date();` function:

For example:

```
$oldFormat = '2019/31/01';
$newFormat = date("d/m/Y",strtotime($yourDate));
```

Here is a reference page:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Hope it works for you!

Comment: thanks. with your pointing me in the right direction I was able to achieve the desired results.             <?$date = $_POST['date']; 
                $oldFormat = '2019/31/01';
                $newFormat = date("F jS, Y",strtotime($date));
            echo $newFormat
            ?>